# Как запустить функцию при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть такой код:

```
pin = tk.Tk()
pin.geometry("300x100")
pin.title("Придумайте пин-код")
pin.resizable(False, False)
pin.configure(bg="gray40")
awe = tk.Entry(pin, width=20, font="Calibri 18")
awe.place(x=25, y=30)
get = awe.get()
sure = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
text = tk.Label(pin, text="Придумайте 4-х значный пин-код", bg="gray40", fg="black", font="Calibri 14")
text.pack()
def sureing(get):
    if get not in sure or get < 4:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Ошибка!","Введите 4 любых числа от 0 до 9")
    else:
        True
regging = tk.Button(pin, width=12, height = 1, text="Подтвердить", bg="Slateblue2", command=sureing(get))
print(get)
regging.place(x=104, y=67)

print(get)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при срабатывании кнопки `regging` началась проверка по символам, введенным пользователем в `get`. Как это сделать?
Также, есть такая проблема, что при запуске программы, `get` проверяется автоматически, но мне это не надо.
Помогите пожалуйста, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не понимаю, почему многие пытаются работать со значениями из полей не в обработчике нажатия на кнопку, а вообще до того, как окно создалось...
В общем, см. комментарии в коде, что было поправлено.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

pin = tk.Tk()
pin.geometry("300x100")
pin.title("Придумайте пин-код")
pin.resizable(False, False)
pin.configure(bg="gray40")
awe = tk.Entry(pin, width=20, font="Calibri 18")
awe.place(x=25, y=30)
text = tk.Label(pin, text="Придумайте 4-х значный пин-код", bg="gray40", fg="black", font="Calibri 14")
text.pack()
def sureing():
    get = awe.get()  # <<< получать значение надо тут, непосредственно после нажатия кнопки
    print(get)
    if not get.isdigit() or len(get) != 4:  # <<< проверка на то, что все символы в строке цифры и длина строки равна 4
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Ошибка!","Введите 4 любых числа от 0 до 9")
    else:
        True
regging = tk.Button(pin, width=12, height = 1, text="Подтвердить", bg="Slateblue2", command=sureing)  # <<< функцию sureing не надо вызывать, а надо передавать, т.е. указывать без круглых скобок
regging.place(x=104, y=67)
pin.mainloop()   # <<< запускается главный цикл работы программы
```